# using output variable as new input variable in perl

Tags: perl

I have a tab-delimited text file in which I do some filtering based on certain column values using a while loop. I write the output to a new file. Now I want to use this output file as an input for another while loop. This is the code that I have so far. Something must be wrong because the `out2.txt` file is empty.

```
my $table1 = $ARGV[0];
open( my $file, $table1 ) || die "$! $table1"; #inputfile
open( my $filter1, '+>', "out.txt" )  || die "Can't write new file: $!"; #first output
open( my $filter2, '+>', "out2.txt" ) || die "Can't write new file: $!"; #second output

while (<$file>) {
    my @line = split /\t/; #split on tabs
    if ( $line[12] =~ /one/ ) { 
        print $filter1 "$_";
    }   
}

while (<$filter1>) {
    my @line = split /\t/; #split on tabs
    if ( $line[11] =~ /two/ ) { 
        print $filter2 "$_";
    }   
}
```

The output file `out.txt` contains the correct information. However the `out2.txt` is empty. Can someone help me with solving this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your script, the "cursor" for the filehandle `$filter1` is always set at the end of the file, while it looks like you want to read from the beginning of the file. You can reset the cursor with the `seek` builtin function.

```
seek $filter1, 0, 0;  # reset $filter1 to start of file
while (<$filter1>) {
    ...
}
```